# Workflow Not Assigning Tasks After Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2016, upgrade

We upgraded a SharePoint 2010 database to 2013 then migrated from classic to claims then upgraded the site appearance then upgraded to 2016, all at once.

Now workflows are advancing and tasks are created but there is no one in the assigned to column.

The workflow is an OOTB approval workflow with 10+ steps.  Multiple active workflows none of which seem to perform as expected.  Workflow history shows it being assigned to the incorrect individual, but the task "Assigned To" is empty.

We've tried editing the current workflow by changing the workflow history list used and by deleting and re-adding each person in the steps.

What could be the reason for this and where can I look?
[image]

Comment: Will look at logs tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The custom things cannot be migrated when migrating from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016.

I suppose there is no method to recover the data which is lost in the “Assigned To” column in the task list.

The workaround for the issue:

You could re-create the workflows in SharePoint 2016 according to the workflows in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: These are not custom workflows.  They are OOTB approval workflows.

Comment: You could check if there is information about the issue in the upgrade log.

Answer (score 0):

Finished a support ticket with Microsoft.  End result is that there was an allowed mismatch in 2010 where the library could have no approval required, but an approval workflow *could* have a check mark to mark approved on completion.  In 2016 this resulted in an Access Denied error because there was no "approved" field.  Thus the workflow would not progress and it was manifested  as no user in the assigned to column and inability to start new workflows.